# Is there any way to write an automation or program on an iPad except Shortcuts?

Tags: ios, automation

I would like to build an interface - a set of menus, for example - which presents information from an app or a webpage and allows me to read and interact with it in a different way than it is presented or accessible in that app or website. I am working on an iPad, so I am considering trying to write some kind of web scraping Shortcut which returns information from the website.

I was curious, is there any other hypothetical way to create an automation, on an iPad? Could there be any tool which could override, control and automate the iPad, even if Apple has made it very difficult to do so?

Answer (score -1):

The only other way I can think of is jailbreaking and using Activator.